# Where does yum install software to?

Tags: centos, installation, yum

When I install executable I know I can easily run `which sometool` and find it (for most cases) but how about when I install something like `apr` or `apr-util` where does it install it to? I need to pass that path to a `./configure` command and can't seem to locate it on my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yum will follow the directions given in the RPM that it is installing. If you want to find out where something got installed, use, for example, 'rpm -ql apr' to see where those files got installed.